# Mapear duas vezes a mesma entidade

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estou tentando mapear duas vezes a mesma entidade em outra

```
public class Conveniado
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(ProcedimentoAgregado.ConveniadoDe))]
    public virtual ICollection<ProcedimentoAgregado> ProcedimentoAgregadoConveniadosDe { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(ProcedimentoAgregado.ConveniadoPara))]
    public virtual ICollection<ProcedimentoAgregado> ProcedimentoAgregadoConveniadosPara { get; set; }
}

public class Procedimento
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(ProcedimentoAgregado.ProcedimentoDe))]
    public virtual ICollection<ProcedimentoAgregado> ProcedimentoAgregadoProcedimentosDe { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(ProcedimentoAgregado.ProcedimentoPara))]
    public virtual ICollection<ProcedimentoAgregado> ProcedimentoAgregadoProcedimentosPara { get; set; }
}

public class ProcedimentoAgregado
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ProcedimentoAgregadoId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Conveniado de")]
    public int ConveniadoDeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Procedimento de")]
    public int ProcedimentoDeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Conveniado para")]
    public int ConveniadoParaId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Procedimento para")]
    public int ProcedimentoParaId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ConveniadoDeId))]
    public virtual Conveniado ConveniadoDe { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ConveniadoParaId))]
    public virtual Conveniado ConveniadoPara { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProcedimentoDeId))]
    public virtual Procedimento ProcedimentoDe { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProcedimentoParaId))]
    public virtual Procedimento ProcedimentoPara { get; set; }
}
```

Ao rodar o `udpate-database` tenho o seguinte erro

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ProcedimentoAgregadoes_dbo.Procedimentoes_ProcedimentoParaId' on table 'ProcedimentoAgregadoes' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Sempre resolvi isso usando o `OnModelCreating` do context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProcedimentoAgregado>()
        .HasRequired(a => a.ProcedimentoPara)
        .WithMany(a => a.ProcedimentoAgregadoProcedimentosPara)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.ProcedimentoParaId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ProcedimentoAgregado>()
        .HasRequired(a => a.ConveniadoPara)
        .WithMany(a => a.ProcedimentoAgregadoConveniadosPara)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.ConveniadoParaId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Ou

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Gostaria de saber se tem outra forma de resolver isso sem ser usando essas duas formas?

A estrutura do banco fica da seguinte maneira
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que você precisa mapear duas vezes se é uma entidade e você já tem uma collection delas?

Comment: Pois é regra de negócio do sistema.

Comment: Mas deveria ser implementada nessa camada? Justamente por se tratar de regra de negócio?

Comment: E em qual camada teria que ser se não na entidade?

Comment: Se tratando de regra de negócio, não deveria estar na entidade, porque o papel dela é refletir a estrutura do banco, se for o caso de você ter uma tabela auxiliar com duas fks para a mesma tabela (Origem e Destino) você deveria ter uma Entidade específica para ela. Mas estou só especulando, adicione o diagrama da sua estrutura de dados

Comment: Mas em que momento a minha entidade não estaria refletindo a estrutura do banco?
Eu uso Migrations pelo EF, a minha estrutura do banco é o que está no mapeamento das minhas entidades.

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma forma mais "limpa" de se mapear a classe, você pode utilizar uma classe Map do tipo `EntityTypeConfiguration` da Fluent API do EF, nela você pode especificar tudo de uma vez relacionado a classe que será configurada, no seu caso acredito que ficaria parecido com isso:

```
public class ProcedimentoAgregadoEntityConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<ProcedimentoAgregado>
{
    public ProcedimentoAgregadoEntityConfiguration()
    {
            this.ToTable("ProcedimentoAgregadoes");

            this.HasKey<Guid>(s => s.ProcedimentoAgregadoId);

            this.HasMany(x => x.ConveniadoPara).HasForeignKey(x => x.ConveniadoParaId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            this.HasMany(x => x.ProcedimentoPara).HasForeignKey(x => x.ProcedimentoParaId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

           //também defina as propriedades required para evitar erros

    }
}
```

E então no seus model builders você pode colocar:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProcedimentoAgregadoEntityConfiguration());
/...
}
```

Se quiser saber como utilizar e o que é Fluent API existe um [site](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx) muito bom para isso.

Também existe um [tópico](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx) focado somente em separar as configurações das entidades em classes separadas.

OBS: não recomendo usar `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>()`, pois pode surgir uma necessidade futura de cascade delete que fará você ter manutenção desnecessária nas classes antigas.

---

Editado conforme requisição do OP nos comentários:

> Eu gostaria de não configurar isso por Fluent API e sim por Data Annotations.

Você pode configurar na própria *model* via *Data Annotation* através da identificação `[ForeignKey("IdForeignKey")]` acima da model relacionada a essa FK como você já fez.
 
Para evitar o cascade delete sem usar a Fluent API as únicas soluções são as que você apresentou ([minha fonte para essa afirmação](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431990/entity-framework-data-annotations-equivalent-of-willcascadeondeletefalse) e [uma fonte com todas Data Annotations para você comprovar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations)), porém você pode setar seu `int`na própria model para `Nullable`, isso fará que o *cascade delete* seja setado como `false` pelo EF, porém não posso dizer se no seu caso essa seja a melhor solução, já que, se você não quiser inserções nulas teria que implementar algumas validações adicionais antes do comando de inserção ser executado.

No caso da model apresentada ficaria assim:

```
public class ProcedimentoAgregado
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ProcedimentoAgregadoId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Conveniado de")]
    public int? ConveniadoDeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Procedimento de")]
    public int? ProcedimentoDeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Conveniado para")]
    public int? ConveniadoParaId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Procedimento para")]
    public int? ProcedimentoParaId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ConveniadoDeId))]
    public virtual Conveniado ConveniadoDe { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ConveniadoParaId))]
    public virtual Conveniado ConveniadoPara { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProcedimentoDeId))]
    public virtual Procedimento ProcedimentoDe { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProcedimentoParaId))]
    public virtual Procedimento ProcedimentoPara { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: eu gostaria de não configurar isso por Fluent API e sim por Data Annotations. O seu exemplo é bem dizer o mesmo do meu onde uso o OnModelCreating, só que vc separou em um arquivo.

Comment: desculpe a demora para responder amigo, vou editar a resposta com uma alternativa usando Data Annotations

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas editado